# How to deploy android APK to firebase app distribution through azure pipeline

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to setup a pipeline that adds the apk to the app distribution in firebase. I have the following yml:

Getting error in `Authenticate Firebase CLI using service account key`.

```yaml
# Step 19: Install Firebase tools.
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Install Firebase Tools'
        inputs:
          script: 'curl -sL firebase.tools | bash'
          workingDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)'

      # Step 20: Authenticate Firebase CLI using service account key.
      - script: |
          echo "$FIREBASE_SA_KEY" > serviceAccountKey.json
          export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/serviceAccountKey.json
          firebase use --add
        displayName: 'Authenticate Firebase CLI'
        env:
          FIREBASE_SA_KEY: $(FIREBASE_SA_KEY)

      # Step 21: Distribute APK to Firebase using Firebase CLI.
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Deploy APK to Firebase'
        inputs:
          script: |
            firebase appdistribution:distribute $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/*uat-release.apk \
            --app "app_id" \
            --release-notes "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ReleaseNotes/combined_release_notes.txt"
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

I don't find that what is wrong and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @raghu Do you have any idea about this?